# Is there an implementation of "getopt" for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, parsing, com

It doesn't get much easier than using getopt() to parse command line parameters in C/C++.

Is there anything similar for Delphi? Or ideally, with the same syntax? I know Delphi supports FindCmdLineSwitch and ParamStr(), but those still require some additional parsing.

I want something that works like getopt() in C. Something that easily allows basic toggle switches, as well as capturing a value after a switch. See below for some example C code to see what I'm talking about:

```
void print_help()
{
        printf("usage:\n") ;
        printf("\t\t-i set input file\n") ;
        printf("\t\t-o set output file\n") ;
        printf("\t\t-c set config file\n") ;
        printf("\t\t-h print this help information\n") ;
        printf("\t\t-v print version\n") ;
}
 char* input_file = NULL ;
        char *query=NULL;
          char opt_char=0;
        while ((opt_char = getopt(argc, argv, "i:q:vh")) != -1)
        {
                switch(opt_char)
                {
                        case 'h':
                                print_help();
                                exit(-1);
                                break;
                        case 'v':
                                print_version() ;
                                exit(-1) ;
                                break ;
                        case 'i':
                                input_file= optarg ;
                                break ;
                        case 'q':
                                query= optarg ;
                                break ;
                        default:
                                print_help();
                                exit(-1);
                                break;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an implementation TGetOpt, claiming to

> implement a getopt variant for Delphi. It is nearly POSIX compatible, supporting long options, required, optional and no arguments

You can find it [here](http://stefan.huberdoc.at/comp/software/delphi/sandkasten.html).

Comment: You should better replace *here* with something like [Sandkasten: useful routines for Delphi programmes | stefan.huberdoc.at](https://stefan.huberdoc.at/sandkasten/) -- who knows the site may go, and then *here* will not be useful.  ...also make clear that TGetOpt comes **included in a collection**.

Comment: @Wolf: I don't think that adds anything, as the browser will still show the link target and allow to copy it to the clipboard even if the link is broken. Anyway, the whole answer is of a kind that has become inappropriate for SO (link to external resources), and I don't really want to push it up to the front page by editing it.

Comment: I see. On the other hand, I often see link targets disappear but their contents moved, in these cases the page title is absolutely helpful. But this is not the only reason, you may have a look at [Why Your Links Should Never Say "Click Here" – Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/)

Answer (score 11):

The **[getopts.pp](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/rtl/inc/getopts.pp?view=markup)** file of the FPC RTL is self contained Delphi (Delphi2009 included) compatible unit that  implements getopt :

> Getopt implementation for Free Pascal,
>   modeled after GNU getopt

The [unit](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/rtl/inc/getopts.pp?view=markup)  is available at the FPC SVN repository.

Answer (score 7):

See TCommandParser, described in this EDN article http://edn.embarcadero.com/print/40404 and available for download on CodeCentral http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27574. TCommandParser should also be included in the Delphi demos now. I made the code freely available to Embarcadero before I left, so hopefully they'll include it in the framework or something like it at some point.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot - CommandParser is actually *included* with the Delphi demos available from the IDE.

Comment: I cannot find `CommandParser` in the included samples, @john-kaster. Also, the links have broken since you posted your answer. Any idea where I could find your class now?

Comment: @BigSmoke both those links still work for me. Sorry it's not still in the demos. Here's some more information on it. https://wiert.me/2015/05/13/on-the-delphi-tcommandparser-class-for-parsing-command-lines-and-arguments-via-suggestions-for-how-to-define-command-line-parameters-stack-overflow/

Answer (score 3):

Nothing built in - but you can make one pretty easily. This should be close to what you are used to

```
TsoCommandLineParser = class
private
  fArguments:TStringList;
public
  constructor Create();
  destructor Destroy(); override;

  function GetOpt(const pArgument:string; const pDefaultValue:string = ''):string;
end;


constructor TsoCommandLineParser.Create();
var
  i:Integer;
begin
  inherited Create();
  fArguments := TStringList.Create();
  for i := 1 to ParamCount() do
  begin
    fArguments.Add(ParamStr(i));
  end;
end;

destructor TsoCommandLineParser.Destroy();
begin
  fArguments.Free();
  inherited Destroy();
end;

function TsoCommandLineParser.GetOpt(const pArgument:string; const pDefaultValue:string = ''):string;
var
  i:Integer;
begin
  i := fArguments.IndexOfName(pArgument);
  if i > -1 then
  begin
    Result := fArguments.ValueFromIndex[i];
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := pDefaultValue;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong about FindCmdLineSwitch in the SysUtils unit?

```
if FindCmdLineSwitch('h',['-'],false) then
  Print_Help();
if FindCmdLineSwitch('v',['-'],false) then
  print_Version();
```

you will have to loop thru the params to get the values, but thats fairly simple to do:

```
if FindCmdLineSwitch('f',['-'],false) then
  for ix := 1 to paramcount do
    if (paramStr(ix) = '-f') and (ix < paramcount) then
      begin
        if fileExists( ParamStr(ix+1) ) then
          filename := ParamStr(ix+1);
        break;
      end
```

Comment: Getopt lets you combine multiple options into a single argument. It also lets you be sure you're processing arguments in order. It has special provisions for allowing arguments that look like options but which are really file names (such as opening a file whose name is "-f" in your example above).

Comment: ah, but if someone has a -f as a filename, and -f is a parameter, then how would it know which was which?

Comment: -f "-f"

Note that you can specify if an option takes a parameter or not.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a new parser called [delphi-argparse](https://github.com/tokibito/delphi-argparse) that is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute-based parser for Delphi can be found [here](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2014/12/attribute-based-command-line-parsing.html).

Comment: I think the page title would be more future-safe than *here* - for example [The Delphi Geek: Attribute-based Command Line Parsing](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2014/12/attribute-based-command-line-parsing.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's the "Gastown Delphi Command Line Parser" which was recently open-sourced (e.g. [on Torry's](http://www.torry.net/quicksearchd.php?String=gastown)). I have never used it, so I can't comment on it.

Comment: Oops, the official sit vanished. But http://www.vclcomponents.com/Delphi/System_Components/Gastown_Command_Line_Parser-info.html looks kosher to me. Maybe http://groups.google.de/group/borland.public.delphi.thirdpartytools.general/browse_frm/thread/1de12d1ad4f08f7 helps, too.