# Example on using getopt.pas

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Could someone provide a simple **example** using getopt.pas with short and long command line switches use case?

**Getopt.pas** is a delphi unit for parsing command line switches.

I've found more than one version of it.

from fpc http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid428067C2ABEF87A674F64BF48FD6E2278E322A18.aspx

The following is another SO question regarding this subject but no example is given; beside it this links to a source that alike the previous links is not self-contained
[Is there an implementation of "getopt" for Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835573/is-there-an-implementation-of-getopt-for-delphi)

Comment: I beg your pardon? I need to run this code. I know what generics are. But Delphi 7? My links above are source of which I need a usage example. Right now I have no examples at all.

Comment: Do you need getopt? What about built-in `FindCmdLineSwitch`?

Comment: @David The answer to your question is: the first link I've posted.
The firebird link was there to tell people that an example for that unit will not suit me. Sorry for the misunderstaing

Comment: @Harriv I would prefer something more advanced; something that decodes me the values of command line switches. That tells me something wrong is going on with wrong switches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a demo of the GPC code that you link to: [getoptdemo.pas [koders.com]](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid122E8911891BEC3EC9D9C43786B528AAB1A02317.aspx?s=md5)