# How to read value of ParamStr with different deliminators?

Tags: delphi, string-comparison, paramstr

When you read `ParamStr()`, it's deliminated by spaces between each parameter. However, I've seen many command-line arguments which accept a space between the parameter name and its paired value, while also accepting an equals `=` sign and even no deliminator (just prefixed with the param name) or no value.

Here's some examples of possible param strings:

```
-name value
/name value
-name=value
/name=value
-namevalue
/namevalue
-name -nextname
/name /nextname
-name="value with spaces"
/name="value with spaces"
```

...etc.

What I would like to do is two things both related... Check if a parameter name exists, and read the value of the parameter. For example...

```
if ParamExists('ParamName') then
  SomeString:= ParamValue('ParamName')
else
  SomeString:= 'SomeOtherString';
```

Is there something in Delphi which can do this? If not, how do I do this? Everything I find when searching for this just leads me to the same basic example:

```
for i := 0 to ParamCount do
  ShowMessage(ParamStr(i));
```

It also needs to be case sensitive. I'm looking for something in particular like `OSQL` and similar command-line tools use where '-s' could be different from '-S'.

The problem is that if I use a space as a deliminator, I have no clue how to recognize when it's part of the previous parameter, because it splits them by spaces. How do I get around this?

I'm sure there's a standard term for this too, it's the common formatting of command-line arguments. But I don't know how to read them properly using just `ParamStr`. It seems `ParamStr` falls short of what it's usually used for.

To be clear, I don't necessarily need to support every above example - those are just examples I've seen before.

Comment: Are you tried the [FindCmdLineSwitch](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.SysUtils.FindCmdLineSwitch) function?

Comment: Do you know this http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.FindCmdLineSwitch ?

Comment: Looks like that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Actually, no, because it uses ParamStr() internally, so it won't handle all of the cases mentioned.

Comment: What I'd do is look for a [**getopt** library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/835573/33732), preferably one that supports the common extensions (like long arguments, optional equal signs, and flexible option and argument ordering). The built-in stuff simply isn't up to the task. Also, use CommandLineToArgvW to split the tokens on the command line so you get parsing consistent with other, non-Delphi programs.

Comment: Seeing an upvote here, actually just last night I wrote my own class for this. Will share shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ParamStr()` (and consequently `FindCmdLineSwitch()`) is not flexible enough to handle all of the examples you have shown.  You will have to call the Win32 API `GetCommandLine()` function and parse it manually.

Comment: Can you expand your answer and tell us which ones it wouldn't be able to handle?

Comment: @MarjanVenema As stated in the documentation (linked twice in comments) FindCmdLineSwitch can handle space and colon as separator between param and value

Comment: @SirRufo: Thanks, I just though adding that information would help SO stand on its own two feet...

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, just last night I wrote something for this, and just a little bit ago found this got up-voted. Here's a class I just wrote encapsulating this:

```
unit CmdLine;

(*
  Command Line Parser
  by Jerry Dodge

  Class: TCmdLine
  - Parses out a command line into individual name/value pairs
  - Concatenates name/value pairs into a command line string
  - Property "ModuleFilename" for the current executable path
  - Property "OpenFilename" for the file to be opened, if any
  - Default property "Values" to read/write name/value pairs
*)

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils;

type
  TCmdLine = class(TObject)
  private
    FItems: TStringList;
    FModuleFilename: String;
    FOpenFilename: String;
    function GetAsString: String;
    procedure SetAsString(const Value: String);
    procedure SetModuleFilename(const Value: String);
    procedure SetOpenFilename(const Value: String);
    function GetValue(const Name: String): String;
    procedure SetValue(const Name, Value: String);
    function GetName(const Index: Integer): String;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Count: Integer;
    function Exists(const N: String; const IgnoreCase: Boolean = False): Boolean;
    property ModuleFilename: String read FModuleFilename write SetModuleFilename;
    property OpenFilename: String read FOpenFilename write SetOpenFilename;
    property AsString: String read GetAsString write SetAsString;
    property Names[const Index: Integer]: String read GetName;
    property Values[const Name: String]: String read GetValue write SetValue; default;
  end;

implementation

{ TCmdLine }

constructor TCmdLine.Create;
begin
  FItems:= TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TCmdLine.Destroy;
begin
  FItems.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TCmdLine.Count: Integer;
begin
  Result:= FItems.Count;
end;

function TCmdLine.Exists(const N: String; const IgnoreCase: Boolean = False): Boolean;
var
  X: Integer;
begin
  Result:= False;
  for X := 0 to FItems.Count-1 do begin
    if IgnoreCase then begin
      if SameText(N, FItems.Names[X]) then begin
        Result:= True;
        Break;
      end;
    end else begin
      if N = FItems.Names[X] then begin
        Result:= True;
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TCmdLine.SetModuleFilename(const Value: String);
begin
  FModuleFilename:= Value;
end;

procedure TCmdLine.SetOpenFilename(const Value: String);
begin
  FOpenFilename:= Value;
end;

function TCmdLine.GetValue(const Name: String): String;
begin
  Result:= FItems.Values[Name];
end;

procedure TCmdLine.SetValue(const Name, Value: String);
begin
  FItems.Values[Name]:= Value;
end;

function TCmdLine.GetAsString: String;
var
  X: Integer;
  Cmd: String;
  Val: String;
begin
  Result:= '"'+FModuleFilename+'"';
  if Trim(FOpenFilename) <> '' then
    Result:= Result + ' "'+FOpenFilename+'"';
  for X := 0 to FItems.Count-1 do begin
    Cmd:= FItems.Names[X];
    Val:= FItems.Values[Cmd];
    Result:= Result + ' -'+Cmd;
    if Trim(Val) <> '' then begin
      Result:= Result + ' ';
      if Pos(' ', Val) > 0 then
        Result:= Result + '"'+Val+'"'
      else
        Result:= Result + Val;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TCmdLine.GetName(const Index: Integer): String;
begin
  Result:= FItems.Names[Index];
end;

procedure TCmdLine.SetAsString(const Value: String);
var
  Str: String;
  Tmp: String;
  Cmd: String;
  Val: String;
  P: Integer;
begin
  FItems.Clear;
  FModuleFilename:= '';
  FOpenFilename:= '';
  Str:= Trim(Value) + ' ';

  //Extract module filename
  P:= Pos('"', Str);
  if P = 1 then begin
    Delete(Str, 1, 1);
    P:= Pos('"', Str);
    Tmp:= Copy(Str, 1, P-1);
    Delete(Str, 1, P);
    FModuleFilename:= Tmp;
  end else begin
    P:= Pos(' ', Str);
    Tmp:= Copy(Str, 1, P-1);
    Delete(Str, 1, P);
    FModuleFilename:= Tmp;
  end;

  Str:= Trim(Str) + ' ';

  //Extract open filename
  P:= Pos('"', Str);
  if P = 1 then begin
    Delete(Str, 1, 1);
    P:= Pos('"', Str);
    Tmp:= Copy(Str, 1, P-1);
    Delete(Str, 1, P);
    FOpenFilename:= Tmp;
  end else begin
    P:= Pos('-', Str);
    if P < 1 then
      P:= Pos('/', 'Str');
    if P < 1 then begin
      P:= Pos(' ', Str);
      Tmp:= Copy(Str, 1, P-1);
      Delete(Str, 1, P);
      FOpenFilename:= Tmp;
    end;
  end;

  Str:= Trim(Str) + ' ';

  //Extract remaining param switches/values
  while Length(Trim(Str)) > 0 do begin
    P:= Pos('-', Str);
    if P < 1 then
      P:= Pos('/', 'Str');
    if P > 0 then begin
      Delete(Str, 1, 1);
      P:= Pos(' ', Str);
      Tmp:= Trim(Copy(Str, 1, P-1));
      Delete(Str, 1, P);
      if Pos('"', Tmp) = 1 then begin
        Delete(Tmp, 1, 1);
        P:= Pos('"', Tmp);
        if P > 0 then
          Delete(Tmp, 1, 1);
      end;
      Cmd:= Tmp;
      Str:= Trim(Str) + ' ';
      if (Pos('-', Str) <> 1) and  (Pos('/', Str) <> 1) then begin
        P:= Pos('"', Str);
        if P = 1 then begin
          Delete(Str, 1, 1);
          P:= Pos('"', Str);
          Tmp:= Copy(Str, 1, P-1);
          Delete(Str, 1, P);
        end else begin
          P:= Pos(' ', Str);
          Tmp:= Copy(Str, 1, P-1);
          Delete(Str, 1, P);
        end;
        Val:= Tmp;
      end else begin
        Val:= '';
      end;
      if Val = '' then
        Val:= ' ';
      FItems.Values[Cmd]:= Val;
    end else begin
      Str:= '';
      raise Exception.Create('Command line parameters malformed ('+Str+')');
    end;
    Str:= Trim(Str) + ' ';
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I recall expanding this class further, and implementing many more things to make it useful for console applications - specifically supporting /? and /h params for "help". You would actually register all possible switches, each one's requirements, and a short description of it. I'll see if I can find it and include it here as well.

Comment: Found something? :-)

Comment: @UliGerhardt Not in a shareable state, I'll need to tidy it up - and actually GitHub seems like a more appropriate place.

Comment: No need to put a lot of work into it - I only stumbled across this and was curious.

Comment: @UliGerhardt Indeed, I have many "dead" projects, for example a `TFloatBar` control mimicking the one in the TeamViewer software - I have a couple people begging me to continue it, but I just don't have the time or patience.

Comment: to use in  delphiXE3 change unit name to uCmdLine (for avoid conflict). In source project .pas use cmdLn := new TCmdLine.create; cmdLn.asString := CmdLine; //full command line

Answer (score 0):

I just rewrite all my proposed answer in order to add some value to it, thank you for your comments:

```
function TForm1.ParamExists(sParamName: String;
  bIgnoreCase: boolean; equalchar : string = '='): Boolean;
begin
  if bIgnoreCase then
    Result := Pos(sParamName + equalChar, cmdLine) > 0
  else
    Result := AnsiPos(sParamName + equalChar, cmdLine) > 0;
end;

function TForm1.ParamValue(sParamName : String; bIgnoreCase : boolean = false;
                           equalchar : string = '='; delimiter : string = '"'): String;
var
  I : Integer;
  scmdLine : String;
begin
  Result := '';
  scmdLine := cmdLine;
  if bIgnoreCase then
    I := Pos(sParamName, scmdLine)
  else
    I := AnsiPos(sParamName, scmdLine);

  inc(I, Length(sParamName + equalchar));

  delete(scmdLine, 1, I-1);
  if pos(delimiter, scmdLine) = 1 then
  begin
    delete(scmdLine, 1, 1);
    Result := copy(scmdLine,1, pos(delimiter, scmdLine) -1);
  end
  else
    Result := copy(scmdLine,1, pos(' ', scmdLine));
end;
```

Supposing this parameters:

```
project1.exe -name1 value1 /name2 value2 -name3=value3 /name4=value4 -name5value5 /name6value6 -name7 -name8 /name9 /name91 -name10="Value 10" /name11="Value 11"
```

Example:

```
ParamExists('-Name1', False, ' '); --> False
ParamExists('-Name1', True, ' '); --> True, ignore case
ParamExists('-name1', False, ' '); --> True
ParamExists('-name1', False, '='); --> False there are no a = after -name1 parameter
ParamExists('-name6', False, ''); --> True this parameter use the form -parameterValue
```

ParameterValue example:

```
ParamValue('-name1', false, ' '); --> value1
ParamValue('/name2', false, ' '); --> value2
ParamValue('-name3'); --> value3, using default values
ParamValue('-name4'); --> value4, using default values
ParamValue('-name5', false, ''); --> value5
ParamValue('/name6', false, ''); --> value6
```

Notice that parameters -name7, -name8, /name9 and /name91 must be evaluated as ParamExists because there are no a value asigned to them.

```
ParamValue('-name10', false, '=', '"'); --> Value 10
same as:
ParamValue('-name10'); --> Value 10

ParamValue('/name11'); --> Value 11
```

Comment: How does this code handle the first two examples the poster provided, which do not have `=` in them? Or the fourth through eighth, which also do not have `=` in them? How does it handle the variations that do not have quotes in them? If you're going to post an answer to a five year old question that has existing answers, yours should add some value.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Ken, I changed my answer in order to add value as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem I made this function it is simple and very useful

```
function GetCmdLineValue(CmdLine: string; Arg: string; Switch: Char; Separator: Char): string;
var
 ArgIndex: Integer;          // Index of Argument
 SepIndex: Integer;          // Index of Separator between Arg and Value ex "=" or ":"
 NextSwitchIndex: Integer;   // Index of the next Arg ex "-"
 LenghtValue: Integer;
begin
     ArgIndex:= CmdLine.IndexOf(Arg);
     SepIndex:= CmdLine.IndexOf(Separator, ArgIndex);
     NextSwitchIndex:= CmdLine.IndexOf(Switch, ArgIndex+1);

     { No Value found then Exit }

       // no separator found
     if (SepIndex = -1) or

       // the separator is located after the next switch
        ( SepIndex > NextSwitchIndex) and (NextSwitchIndex > -1) then Exit('');

     if NextSwitchIndex = -1 then   // No switch after Arg
        LenghtValue:= CmdLine.Length - SepIndex+2
     else
        LenghtValue:= NextSwitchIndex - SepIndex-1;

     Result:= Copy(CmdLine, SepIndex+2, LenghtValue).Trim;
end;
```

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0qwZ.png)

[image]

uses:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     edt_Value.Text:= GetCmdLineValue(edt_CmdLine.Text, edt_Argum.Text, '-', '=');
end;
```

Comment: You're reading command-line arguments ....from a form?